# How to pass list in Pyspark function "Withcolumn"

Tags: python-3.x, database, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am doing ltrim and rtrim on multiple columns of dataframe but now i am able to do it individually . like

```
# selected_colums = selected_colums.withColumn("last_name", ltrim(selected_colums.last_name))
# selected_colums = selected_colums.withColumn("last_name", rtrim(selected_colums.last_name))

# selected_colums = selected_colums.withColumn("email", ltrim(selected_colums.email))
# selected_colums = selected_colums.withColumn("email", rtrim(selected_colums.email))

# selected_colums = selected_colums.withColumn("phone_number", ltrim(selected_colums.phone_number))
# selected_colums = selected_colums.withColumn("phone_number", rtrim(selected_colums.phone_number))
```

But I want to do it in loop like below

```
sdk = ['first_name','last_name','email','phone_number','email_alt','phone_number_alt']
for x in sdk:
  selected_colums = selected_colums.withColumn(x, ltrim(selected_colums.last_name))
```

Its giving me syntax error.
Please help me to optimize this code so that for any number of column i can able to do ltrim or rtrim just passing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

Import required functions

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col
```

Apply `ltrim` and `rtrim` on all columns

```
>>> columnExprs = map(lambda c: rtrim(ltrim(col(c))).alias(c),df.columns)
```

Apply columnExprs in select

```
df.select(*columnExprs).show()
```